# Returning wrong DateTime in search results by using KeywordQuery

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

I have a big problem. I am using KeywordQuery in server side code to return items from several lists with same contenttypeid. I have in those list some datetime columns. When i return the value from the keywordwquery search i get

```
3/2/2017 11:00:00 PM
```

But i saved 3/3/2017 as date in the list item! What is wrong here? Why am i receiving always the date - 1 hour from the search database and how can i correct this in my server side code?

This is my code:

```
            SearchServiceApplicationProxy proxy = (SearchServiceApplicationProxy)SearchServiceApplicationProxy.GetProxy(SPServiceContext.GetContext(querySite));

            using (KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(proxy))
            {
                try
                {
                    keywordQuery.ResultsProvider = SearchProvider.Default;
                    keywordQuery.StartRow = 0;
                    keywordQuery.RowLimit = 9999;
                    keywordQuery.EnableStemming = false;
                    keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = false;
                    keywordQuery.AuthenticationType = QueryAuthenticationType.PluggableAuthenticatedQuery;
                    keywordQuery.KeywordInclusion = KeywordInclusion.AllKeywords;

                    keywordQuery.QueryText = "contentclass:\"STS_ListItem_Task\" NOT ContentTypeId:\"0x010800C140B62AF5566C4CBFC76C53B8D4DA94\"";

                    keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("Author");
                    keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("AssignedTo");
                    keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("DueDate");
                    keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("StartDate");
                    keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("path");
                    keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("title");

                    SearchExecutor executor = new SearchExecutor();
                    ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = executor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
                    var resultTables = resultTableCollection.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);
                    ResultTable resultTable = resultTableCollection.FirstOrDefault();

                    if (resultTable.Table.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                       ...
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's the time zone shift that comes into play here. Check which time is local and which is UTC.